# What are the possible filter content types with a response in chrome debugger

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There are various filter content types available currently
 XHR, Document, JS, CSS and many

see this to find what there types are about 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#filter_requests

One of these types are given as `type` property of third argument of this function `addListener` callback https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#event-onEvent

I am just trying to find if there enum list exists.
If yes, where can i find it
If not, then how these type values are generated.

Comment: i just does not understand the down votes without a comment...! I don't care votes but just your viewpoints...!

Answer (score 0):

After no documentations,

I just tried to open debugger over chrome debugger.

And so i could inspect the HTML and view JS files by Sources tab of debugging window.

I found inspector.js file at the root directory.
Then i prettied it, and found this :

[image]

So we can see the enum list of resource category/types (filter types in my previous words)